# Dijkstra's algorithm: How do you choose the edge source and destination

Tags: java, algorithm

I was reading [***Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in Java***](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html)

I implemented my own version of Dijkstra's algorithm. I can post it if necessary.

My question is, does it matter how you define an edge? Is the order of the start and end nodes significant?

For example

```
addLane("Edge_0", 0, 1, 85);
addLane("Edge_1", 0, 2, 217);
addLane("Edge_2", 0, 4, 173);
addLane("Edge_3", 2, 6, 186);
addLane("Edge_4", 2, 7, 103);
addLane("Edge_5", 3, 7, 183);
addLane("Edge_6", 5, 8, 250);
addLane("Edge_7", 8, 9, 84);
addLane("Edge_8", 7, 9, 167);
addLane("Edge_9", 4, 9, 502);
addLane("Edge_10", 9, 10, 40);
addLane("Edge_11", 1, 10, 600);
```

What if I changed the last line to:

```
addLane("Edge_11", 10, 1, 600);
```

2nd 3rd and 4th argument is the node_source, node_end, and distance?

In my implementation I had to change the order around for one edge to get it to work? Is that a problem with my algorithm?

Comment: Yes it does make a difference when you're graph is directed. `1 10` means you can go from `1` to `10` and not the other way around.

Comment: Hint: If you have undirected edges, they go in both directions

Comment: What if they were bidirectional? for example the subway/tube map?

Comment: If they are bidirectional for every `(a,b)` you should have `(b,a)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined rule.

It's either part of the statement/documentation or the graph can be bidirectional (you can go both from a to b and b to a on the same edge).
It usually clear from the context.